# Problems with Sourcetree

Tags: git, merge, branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I am having lots of problems with Sourcetree and Git and last time I tried to sort it on my own I lost an entire branch of work.

I created a branch and comitted to it a couple of times. Once the work was finished I wanted to merge with my Origin/Master branch.
So I checkedout Origin/Master and rightclicked the new branch and pressed merge.

Once succeeded I ended up with a master branch which is 2 ahead of my Origin / Master branch which I wanted to merge in to.

[image]

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong and how I resolve this to get back to the Origin / Master branch?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I am being an idiot. I forgot to push my changes